# What is the command to know my PulseAudio version?

Tags: 10.10, pulseaudio

What is the command to know my PulseAudio version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
pulseaudio --version
```

This should give you an output something like this:

```
pulseaudio 0.9.21-63-gd3efa-dirty
```

To get the version of the Debian package you have installed, use:

```
dpkg -l pulseaudio
```

which will give output like this:

```
||/ Name             Version          Description
+++-================-================-================================================
ii  pulseaudio       1:0.9.22~0.9.21+ PulseAudio sound server
```

Comment: Do you know how to upgrade to version 0.9.22?

Comment: I don't but someone else might - you should ask this as another question.